# Read nested Dictionary in JSON object from WCF Service

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf, serialization

I have created a JSON object using VB.NET

```
   {
  "MasDatos": {
    "Cosas": "Yo que se",
    "MasCosas": "Ni  idea",
    "OtroArray": [
      "Cosa 1",
      "Cosa 2",
      "Cosa 3"
    ]
  },
  "nombre": "Person Name",
  "apellidos": "Second Name",
  "edad": 19,
  "Gustos": [
    "Gusto 1",
    "Gusto 2"
  ]
}
```

I Send this code to my WCF Service on "POST" Method. I can read all variables, for example.

If i want to read "edad" i can do something like this in my wcf service method...

```
public String readParameter(String edad){
return edad;
}
```

above code works. But I CANT read "MasDatos" values. That is a Dictionary. But im not able to retrieve it.

If you see, "Gustos" is an array. I can read it doing this

```
public string readValue(array Gustos){
//Logical stuff
}
```

i've tried doing this to read "MasDatos"

```
public string readDicto(List<String,Object> myNewDictionary){
return somestring;
}
```

but myNewDictionary is null everytime...

Please forgive my horrible english. I hope someone can help me =)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why is List the type of myNewDictionary?

Comment: Think about it like a NSDictionary, is a list of objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, answer is quite simple.

Use classes with [datacontract] and [datamember] tags to map complex json objects